# Cartoon about a door leading to a world full of magic

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic, cartoon

A girl who accidentally sees a girl/boy enter the door and then vanish. Then the next day she found out that door is magic, because she tried to open the door and the next thing that happened is she's falling from the sky.

I first saw this cartoon on TV, and I forgot the title.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it's the one your looking for but the only one I can remember that was similar to what you described is called 'Regal Academy'. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regal_Academy):

> Rose is off on her first day of high school, but is almost late after stopping at shoe shop after shoe shop, whereupon she receives a magical key from a mouse. Bumping into a strange boy holding a similar key, she follows him to an alleyway, where he unlocks a door and jumps in. Following suit, Rose winds up at Regal Academy, a school for fairytales, and is welcomed by her grandmother Cinderella, the headmistress of the school. There, she is made to attend classes with group-mates Astoria Rapunzel, Joy LeFrog, Hawk SnowWhite and Travis Beast, the boy she bumped into earlier.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It'd be great if you could edit this answer to tell us a bit more about the show and help clarify how closely it matches the OP's description.